# IOException: broken pipe when sending file from android device to PC via Bluetooth

Tags: java, android, eclipse, bluetooth, broken-pipe

I'm working on a project where I try to send any file from my phone to my PC.
I made the following steps and they all work well:

1. Find out available device to connect
2. Pairing the Bluetooth device
3. Connecting to PC using BluetoothSocket.

The problem happens when I try to write `byte[]` to PC using `BluetoothOutputStream`.

```
InputStream fis = null;
    OutputStream os = null;
        if (isConnected && toSend != null) {
            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream(toSend);
                os = socket.getOutputStream();
                byte[] buf = new byte[2048];
                if(socket.isConnected()){
                    while ((fis.read(buf)) != -1) {
                        os.write(buf);
                    }
                    os.flush();
                    Log.i("tag", "write complete");
                }
                Log.i("tag", "socket is not yet connected");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

When it gets to `os.write()`, a

> ioexcoption: broken pipe

is shown in eclipse logcat and I receive nothing on my PC.

Does anyone know how to handle this problem? I figure that my PC is the cause.